# How to access ObservableCollection from another ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a BaseViewModel where I define my ObservableCollection and then I populate it. In another ViewModel I have a Grid and I bind it to my collection, everything works.

```cs
public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Patient> patientInfo;

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        PopulateObservableCollection();
    }

    public void PopulateObservableCollection()
    {
        PatientInfo = new ObservableCollection<Patient>();
        try
        {
            string query = "select * from " + App.userDetails.DbTable;
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    PatientInfo.Add(new Patient(Convert.ToInt32(row[0]), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString(), row[6].ToString(), row[7].ToString(), row[8].ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change my ObservableCollection from the other ViewModels and be able to access the memory from the BaseViewModel.

Next a ViewModel where I try to change the ObservableCollection, but I'm not accessing the objected created in the BaseViewModel:

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(Patient), nameof(Patient))]
public partial class EditingViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty] private Patient patient;
    
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "DELETE from " + App.userDetails.DbTable + " WHERE id = @patientId";
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientId", Patient.Id);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            //Removing object from observable collection
            PatientInfo.Remove(PatientInfo.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == Patient.Id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Aplicaçao", ex.ToString(), "Sair");
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My "DashboardView" where the grid is defined:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="PatientAppMultiPlatf.Views.DashboardPage"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PatientAppMultiPlatf.ViewModels"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid"
             Title="Lista de Pacientes">

    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10">
        <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="20" >
            <Button 
                   Text="Exportar" Command="{Binding PDFCommand}" CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="End">
            </Button>
            <Button
                Text="Filtrar" Command="{Binding FilterCommand}" WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            </Button>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Date}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Data"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Nome"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Age}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Idade"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Gender}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Genero"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Process}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Processo"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Diagnostic}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Diagnostico"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="45" Padding="5" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White">
                <Entry Text="{Binding Discharge}" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Alta"/>
            </Frame>

        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" DefaultColumnWidth="90"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PatientInfo}" SortingMode="Single" SelectedRow="{Binding SelectedPatient}" SelectionMode="Single"
                               HeightRequest="600"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" AutoGenerateColumnsMode="None">
            <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="CellDoubleTapped"
                    Command="{Binding CellDoubleTappedCommand}">
                </toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Behaviors>
            <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Data" MappingName="Date"/>
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Nome" MappingName="Name" ColumnWidthMode="Fill"/>
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Idade" MappingName="Age"/>
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Genero" MappingName="Gender"/>
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Processo" MappingName="Process"/>
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Diagnostico" MappingName="Diagnostic" ColumnWidthMode="Fill"/>
                <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn  HeaderText="Alta" MappingName="Discharge" ColumnWidthMode="LastColumnFill"/>
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.DefaultStyle>
                <syncfusion:DataGridStyle HeaderRowBackground="#b2cbc8" HeaderRowTextColor="Black" />
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.DefaultStyle>
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Each view has a xaml.cs where I bind the page to the view model:

```cs
namespace PatientAppMultiPlatf.Views;

public partial class DashboardPage : ContentPage
{
    public DashboardPage(DashboardViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

I'm using MVVM architecture. What is the best method to access the ObservableCollection that is being binded?

Comment: I take it both contexts exist at the same time. In that case, you can retrieve it from any Control within the Page with the given context. As long both have same parent for example window

Comment: Does your page have 2 viewmodels?

Comment: I have 1 ViewModel for each Page/View

Comment: @FreakyAli there aren't two Viewmodels. He does not understand well inheritance. This is the same object.

Comment: @JoaoLima You can try to make BaseViewModel class implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead of ObservableObject.

Answer (score 3):

In the `BaseViewModel`, change

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Patient> patientInfo;
```

to

```
[ObservableProperty]
protected ObservableCollection<Patient> patientInfo;
```

Comment: Aw, yes. Significant improvement over my answer. Placing protected instead of public ensures the encapsulation principle of objective oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollections are not ObservableProperties.

The change to the collection itself is more than enough to notify any changes.

If I am concerned about setting it to something else, I usually do this:

```
**public** ObservableCollection MyProperty {get;} = new();
```

Also, I do not see anywhere your x:DataType. Why are you not setting it, and why is your VisualElement named?

Edit: I am not sure I put enough stress on the word PUBLIC, so I want to point it out again here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code,I created a demo and it could remove the item from `PatientInfo` which inherits from the properties of the parent class( `BaseViewModel`)

You can refer to the following code:

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```
public partial class BaseViewModel: ObservableObject 
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Patient> patientInfo;

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        PopulateObservableCollection();
    }

    public void PopulateObservableCollection()
    {
        PatientInfo = new ObservableCollection<Patient>();
        try
        {
            PatientInfo.Add(new Patient { Id = 01, Name="test1"});
            PatientInfo.Add(new Patient { Id = 02, Name = "test2" });
            PatientInfo.Add(new Patient { Id = 03, Name = "test3" });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
}

public class Patient 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**EditingViewModel.cs**

```
  public partial class EditingViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        //[ObservableProperty] private Patient patient;

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task Delete()
        {
            try
            {

                //Removing object from observable collection
                
                 //here I could remove the item from PatientInfo from parent class `BaseViewModel `

                PatientInfo.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Aplicaçao", ex.ToString(), "Sair");
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:MauiMvvmApp="clr-namespace:MauiMvvmApp226"
             x:Class="MauiMvvmApp226.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <MauiMvvmApp:EditingViewModel></MauiMvvmApp:EditingViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PatientInfo}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Id}"
                              Detail="{Binding Name}"
                              TextColor="#f35e20"
                              DetailColor="#503026" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

            <Button
                
                Command="{ Binding DeleteCommand}"
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks Jessie, I also came to the conclusion I could change the collection. The problem I have is that my UI is not changing when the Collection is getting modified. When the funtion Populate() is called the grid is filled, so the binding is correct, but if I remove an item from the collection the UI doesn't update. Am I setting something wrong with the [ObservableProperty]?

Comment: I could not reproduce this problem on my side.  Could you please post a basic demo here so that I can test on my side?